# How to replace multiple strings in a text file and generate the logfile simultaneously?

Tags: powershell

There are multiple text files in a folder and there are multiple affected IDs in each text file. I need to replace them with new IDs. Also, I want to generate a text log file listing the filename,oldID,newID . This log file is required for crosschecking and validation. 
 I have a csv file from which I am creating a array IdList. I have listed the part of code for replacing the string below.

```
foreach ($f in gci -r -include "*.txt")
{
Set-Variable -Name filename -value ($f.name)


for( $i=0; $i -le $elementCount; $i++)
 {
Write-Host $i
$oldString= $IdList[$i].OLD_ID+','+$IdList[$i].OLD_ID_TYPE
$newString= $IdList[$i].NEW_ID+','+$IdList[$i].NEW_ID_TYPE

 gc $f.fullname|ForEach-Object {if($_.contains($oldString)){ "$filename,$oldString,$newString" >> $logFile; $_ -replace $oldString,$newString}}| sc $f.fullname

 } 

}
```

I am getting error :

```
Set-Content : The process cannot access the file 'U:\testScript\rapg6785.txt' because it is being used by another process.
At line:22 char:152
+      gc $f.fullname|ForEach-Object {if($_.contains($oldString)){ "$filename,$oldString,$newString" >> $logFile; $_ -replace $oldString,$newString}}| sc <<<<  $f.fullname
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-Content], IOException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetContentCommand
```

Comment: try putting `gc $f.fullname` in brackets: `(gc $f.fullname)`

Comment: thanks CB. it is working with (gc $f.fullname). Can you also tell the what is the difference with and without brackets?

Comment: Added as an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try putting gc `$f.fullname` in brackets: `(gc $f.fullname)`.

In this way the pipeline starts when `gc` ends to read the file and free the file handle to be used by another process.